# Web page/part page rewind animation, like github

Tags: animation, jquery-plugins, plugins

Please advice js/jquery library/plugin for making page/part page rewind (horizontal scroll)
of content/full page like in github.
Or advice how I can realise it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have explained how to achieve it.[Please take a look](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)

In summary, you need a [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html), CSS3 transitions and some server side setup. To support it in cross browser, you may need to use some polyfill plugin to achive it.

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)

For CSS3 transitions in IE, there are no promised polyfill.

You may like a library [pajax from github](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) which combine the ajax request and history api.